# Android ProgressDialog not showing (blocked by code in other Thread)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Looking to similar questions everybody solve the problem of not appearing their Progress Dialog putting the intermediate code in a separate Thread.

My problem is that the mentioned solution is not working for me.

In my activity:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_ddbb_download_text)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.Accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // In this method I show the progress dialog
                        showProgressAndDownloadDDBB();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        builder.create().show();
```

Method in the activity:

```
private void showProgressAndDownloadDDBB() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();
    // Here I call the Runnable to execute the code in other Thread and let the UI draw the Progress Dialog. If it wasn't called, the progress dialog does appear.
    DDBB_Download_Manager ddbb_download_manager = new DDBB_Download_Manager(mContext, progressDialog);
    ddbb_download_manager.run();
}
```

My runnable class, expected to run the intermediate code in a separate Thread:

```
public class DDBB_Download_Manager implements Runnable {


public DDBB_Download_Manager(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mProgresDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    someCode()
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    // The GUI shows the accept Button clicked for 3 seconds (like it was freezed)
    // Here I try to hide the Progress dialog after finishing the job, but it doesn't matter becasuse the progress dialog didn't even show up.
    View rootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    rootView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgresDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

So the question is:
if I am executing the code between the Show and Dismiss methods of the Progress Dialog in a different Thread than the UI Thread, why is not the dialog showing up?

Comment: and where should this progress bar should be showing?

Comment: In the activity where I create an Alert Dialog. In that activity after clicking Positive button I call showProgressAndDownloadDDBB() and inside this method I show the Progress Dialog so I guess it should appear in that activity. In fact it appears If I don't call the Runnable.

Comment: Calling the `run` method on a `Runnable` doesn't run it on a separate thread. Also, is the code in `someCode()` running on a separate thread?

Comment: I have added a Thread.sleep(3000); in the code. So between the Show and the Dismiss are a 3 seconds lapse where the Progess Dialog should appear due to this code is in a Runnable.

I don't understand "why calling run method on a Runnable doesn't run on a separate Thread". I thought that it do run in a separate thread because of the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`In fact it appears If I don't call the Runnable.`

That is because you are running directly the `dismiss()` method from the runnable when you call `ddbb_download_manager.run()` where the progress dialog is cleared/done and if you are not calling it then the progress dialog will show due to that dismiss is on yet been called.

Make sure that you call `ddbb_download_manager.run()` when you want your progress dialog to be dismissed. don't call it directly after you show your progress dialog.

```
private void showProgressAndDownloadDDBB() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();
    // Here I call the Runnable to execute the code in other Thread and let the UI draw the Progress Dialog. If it wasn't called, the progress dialog does appear.
    DDBB_Download_Manager ddbb_download_manager = new DDBB_Download_Manager(mContext, progressDialog);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(ddbb_download_manager ,3*1000);
}
```

Comment: I added a 3 second lapse to let  you know that is not dismissing as fast as I am not able to see it. :)
Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @JoseLuisMartínRomera due to `Thread.sleep(3000);` ur main thread will go to sleep therefore you are waiting for the next execution of the next line for three second

Comment: I've solved the problem this way:  `Thread thread = new Thread(ddbb_download_manager);
  thread.start();` Instead of handler. 
I don't understand why in the doc they don't explain that when they say that a Runnable runs on a separate Thread...

Comment: @JoseLuisMartínRomera `runnable` is meant to be used by a thread where you run your code within the `run` method